# Getting No source available when I'm trying to run tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

When I try to run tests in my project it doesn't run them and gives me the message "No source available". I have searched for this problem and tried different solutions but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/274 help? Have you installed the appropriate NUnit adapter from Nuget?

Comment: What 'different solutions' have you tried? It can helps us determine if we should spend time writing one down ;) Did you check to see if you have all references you need, like [runners](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Runners/)?

Comment: The project is an exercise from school which has all the extensions already pre-installed and works for other students from my school. I have tried setting the Default Processor Architecture in both Menu > Test and Solution > Properties > Build to x64 which didn't change anything.

Comment: Done. It's really frustrating since it's working for everyone else..

Comment: Try this: Close Visual Studio, go to `%LocalAppData%\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` and delete the folder for the NUnit TestAdapter. Then start Visual Studio and load the solution.

Comment: Done and didn't work. I noticed there is an error however. Which is: `Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\Sinan\OneDrive\Programming Adv\NET\Opdrachten\FizzBuzzTDD  - Skelet\FizzBuzzSametSinan\FizzBuzz.Web.Tests\bin\Debug\FizzBuzz.Web.Tests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`

Comment: After restarting my laptop it started working..